# Input wont return true when using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Attempting to log the input that the following gives me. But I am unable to even get anything other then false when attempting to type in the box. As in i'm able to type a single character, have it return true and then almost immediately it choses to no longer respond and always returns false no matter what I type inside of the box.

```js
function search() {
  var value = document.getElementById("search").value;
  console.log(value == ''); // true
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeydown="search()" id="search"></input>
```

Testing - Chrome 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit)

Comment: try to use keyup event and check for value.length == 0

Comment: Check this.. http://jsfiddle.net/8x1e3skk/

Comment: As soon as you type something the value is not an empty string, so the test will always be false. Why do you expect it to return `true`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, went stupid. Im trying to get a response in which would see what the user had typed and then log it in the Javascript console for testing purposes. I needed to show id made an attempt and as of such I posted what code I had made here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your trying to compare strings. When you do the comparison with a == it is looking at values. You need to use === then you will be able to check if the input is equal to whatever you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard events is one of wilder parts of frontend development. There are inconsistencies and cross-browser problems.

But still there are recipes which help to cope with ordinary situations easily.

There are following keyboard events:

- keydown

A key is pressed down.

- keypress

A character key is pressed.

- keyup

A key is released.
There is a fundamental difference between keypress and keydown.

`Keydown` triggers on any key press and gives scan-code.
`Keypress` triggers after `keydown` and gives char-code, but it is guaranteed for character keys only.

> You need to use `keyup`, because it triggers after `keypress`.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="search()" id="search"></input>
```

see [KeyEvents](http://javascript.info/tutorial/keyboard-events)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated [**`JSFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/8x1e3skk/9/)

You have to use keyup event because you want result after the key is pressed.